# How to create a nested mutation with an empty child in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

How would I create a post and an author, while the author has no required fields?

Something like:

```
mutation {
  createPost(
    text: "This is a post!"
    author: {
      // ???
    }
  ) {
    id
    author {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn the [nested mutation](https://www.graph.cool/docs/reference/simple-api/nested-create-mutations-vaet3eengo/) around:

```
mutation {
  createUser(posts: [{
    text: "This is a post!"
  }]) {
    id
  }
}
```

I assume it's a **one-to-many** relation and the fields is called `posts`.